# google.visualization.DataTable(<?php $jdata ?>)?

Tags: php, google-visualization

I am trying to produce a chart using Google visualization and php/mysql.
My data looks like this:

```
      ['RTI', 3],
      ['USAID', 1],
      ['Task Force', 1],
      ['DFID', 1],
      ['Other', 2]
```

If I print $jdata I get:

```
[{"Response":"Other","Count":"3"},{"Response":"RTI","Count":"3"},{"Response":"USAID","Count":"4"}]
```

which looks pretty close.  Any advice?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {
```

```
    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php $jdata ?>);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':"Question1: I'm here to represent:",
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `<?php echo $jdata ?>` You forgot an echo?

Answer (score 2):

`<?php $jdata ?>` does nothing - you need to echo it - `<?php echo $jdata ?>`!

Comment: Or shorttags (if enabled) `<?=$jdata?>`, +1

Comment: @cyclone: in PHP 5.4, `<?=` is always available.